# Show default value of select item from dropdown in input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown looks like following:

```
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero" >
    <select id="ddlCompare1" class="dropdown" onChange="javascript:CompareLoantype(true);" >
        <option value="jumbo">Conv</option>
        <option selected  value="fha">FHA</option>
        <option value="va">VA</option>
        <option value="usda">USDA</option>
    </select>                                    
</div>
```

I want the selected default value to be asigned to the following input :

```
  <input name="Compare_interest_rate" id="Compare_interest_rate" class="txt"   type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" style="width:75%" />%</p>
```

I have the default values of the options on `php`, how can i point to them when i select items.

**FHA value =>** `<?php echo $interest_FHA_default; ?>`

**VA value =>** `<?php echo $interest_VA_default;?>`

**USDA value =>** `<?php echo $interest_USDA_default;?>`

**CONV  value =>** `<?php echo $interest_CONV_default;?>`

How to show value in input depending on item selected in dropdown?  if user select `FHA` item i need `FHA` default value in input?

Comment: What you mean by _all four option value have single interest rate_ ?

Comment: four option in drop down list   four have different value   its show value single input box  based on user selection drop down value .

Comment: Please properly format ur question. Its quite difficult to understand

Comment: Where is `CompareLoantype()` funtion?

Comment: i have four drop down  value like fha,usda,va,conv. that four type have different defaults value but i have single input fields for value show i need show value if user which select  if user select fha . that fha value  needs to display  input text box

Comment: Zakaria Acharki @ please see my update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this what you want, when the user select from drop down the default value shown in the input (default value stored in `data-default` attribut).

**NOTE :** in my example i can't use php code that why i fix the values in `data-default`, you can replace the numbers by the php code for every item, e.g :

```
<option data-default='<?php echo $interest_FHA_default; ?>' value="fha">FHA</option>
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('#ddlCompare1').change(function(){
    $('#Compare_interest_rate').val($(this).find(':selected').data('default'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero" >
    <select id="ddlCompare1" class="dropdown">
        <option data-default='1' value="jumbo">Conv</option>
        <option data-default='2' value="fha" selected>FHA</option>
        <option data-default='3' value="va">VA</option>
        <option data-default='4' value="usda">USDA</option>
    </select>                                    
</div>

 <input name="Compare_interest_rate" id="Compare_interest_rate" class="txt"   type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" style="width:75%" />%</p>
```

Comment: super its correct but i have value in php echo format .. can i pass value   php value data default ?

Comment: bro.. i  have one more doubt .. default value only bind calculation . if user change the value  that value  value bind in text box

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to do, but if you mean that you've to do some calculation when the value change, you can what you want in `.change()` event.